# Manual registration not being recorded into workshop (price set) count.

Tags: civireport

We have an event that has workshops (configured as a price set). When we do a manual (not member / user driven) registration of any person, that information is not being tracked in the workshop reports (price set count for workshop). Can anyone help tell us why this might not be being recorded?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - it was in the report filtering. I cleared a few, and the missing records were found.....

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct one :)